# How to insert $_POST from Java

Tags: java, php, sql

I am trying to insert a $_POST array into a mysql database. The foreach works but not all values are inserted on the same row as you can see on the image below.

[image: Img1]

This is the foreach that i use to insert the array into the database:

```
if($_POST)
{

    // con->insert is my mysql function to insert the values
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($con->insert('test',$key, $value)==true)
        {
            echo 'Het werkt!!!';
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
This is the con function

```
public function insert($table,$row,$value) {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connect, "INSERT INTO `$table` (`$row`) VALUES ('$value')");

        if ($query == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I want to collect the variables from the post and then i want to put them in the database on the same row of the table.

How can i get the values on the same row?
Thank in advance

Comment: Where does Java come into play?

Comment: What kind of object is `$con`?

Comment: @Thilo Im posting values from Java

Comment: @jsalonen I've put the con function in the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values get into different rows because you are doing one insert per variable.

You probably want to collect all variables from the $_POST and add them to the database in a single insert.

Firstly, change your insert clause like this:

```
public function insert_multi($table, $items) {
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,
        "INSERT INTO `$table` (`firstKeyName`, `secondKeyName`) ".
        "VALUES ('".$items['firstKeyName']."', '".$items['secondKeyName']."')");

        if ($query == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then call it only once with all params:

```
$con->insert_multi('test', $_POST);
```

Comment: I want to do that but how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you are doing one insert command for every value, when you should be doing one for every key and value pair.

One option you can try is to insert the $_POST array as JSON data.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect(...);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT into `table` VALUES ($key, $value)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT INTO `$table` (`$row`) VALUES ('$value')

Normally (if this is not phpMySqlAdmin that you are writing), your application knows what columns are available for a given table, and you totally need to validate the values for $row, otherwise it is a terrible potential for SQL injection.

And if you have a list of column names, you can do

```
INSERT INTO test (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

and you can give it the array

```
$_POST["COL1"], $_POST["COL2"], $_POST["COL3"]
```